# Pegar data pela url (string not was recognized datetime)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, url

Estou passando uma data inicial e final por parâmetro (conforme a imagem), como podem visualizar no localhost as barras (/) estou passando %20 e ocorre normalmente a geração dos gráficos, porém no servidor está acusando erro 500 e ao inspecionar vejo que tem a mensagem "string not was recognized datetime". O que pode está ocorrendo já que no localhost funciona e no servidor não?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
        function urldecode(str) {
        return decodeURIComponent((str + '').replace(/\+/g, '%20'));
    }
```

Aqui ao carregar página:

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
        var data = getParameterByName('data');
        var start = urldecode(getParameterByName('dataInicio'));
        var end = urldecode(getParameterByName('dataFinal'));

        DrawonLoad(start, end, "bottom", 300, "center", 10, data);
        buscaAtosPraticados();
        DrawonLoad2(start, end, "bottom", 300, "center", 10, data);
        buscaCertidoes();
        DrawonLoad3(start, end, "bottom", 300, "center", 10, data);
        buscaBalcaoCRT();
    });
```

Aqui onde chamo o ajax:

```
function DrawonLoad(dataInicio, dataFinal, posicaoLegenda, tamanho, alinhamento, tamanhoFonte, data) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Home/FiltroData?dataInicio=' + urldecode(dataInicio) + '&dataFinal=' + urldecode(dataFinal) + '&data=' + data,
            success: function (chartsdata) {
```

Comment: a sua função não deveria ser para encode ao invés de decode?

Answer (score 0):

Então, não necessitou nada disso acima, era apenas que o servidor estava com o formato em inglês. Então, adicionei no projeto (webconfig):

```
 <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```